# How do I properly configure the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" setting with the job dsl? What is "spec"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I currently configure this setting with the job DSL like this:

```
    it / 'triggers' << 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger'{
        spec 'H H/4 * * *'
        interval "43200000" // 12 hours
    }
```

I don't understand the spec argument. I first made the config in the UI and just looked at the job xml and used those parameters.

[image]

This is what the config looks like if I set it to 30 mins in the UI:

```
<com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.729.v2b_9d1a_74d673">
  <spec>H/5 * * * *</spec>
  <interval>1800000</interval>
</com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger>
```

The interval setting is obvious, but what is spec? The UI gives me one argument but the job DSL has two. I can't find documentation on this.

What is "spec" here? Is it the time of day the interval begins? Why doesn't the UI surface this argument?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the job-dsl-plugin older versions:  [JENKINS-55429](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55429) that was fixed.

As explained try to use the Dynamic DSL, like in this example:

```
organizationFolder('example'){
    description('This contains branch source jobs for Bitbucket and GitHub')
    displayName('Organization Example')
    triggers {
        periodicFolderTrigger {
            interval('12h')
        }
    }
}
```

If the above doesn't work, try to use a configure block:

```
organizationFolder('example'){
    description('This contains branch source jobs for Bitbucket and GitHub')
    displayName('Organization Example')
    configure {
        it / 'triggers' / 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger'(plugin: 'cloudbees-folder@6.729.v2b_9d1a_74d673') {
           spec('H/5 * * * *')
           interval(1800000)
       }
  }
}
```